# How do i remote include a javascript file in Titanium appcelerator and use the functions of that file?

Tags: javascript, scripting, appcelerator

I am required to remotely include into my appcelerator project, a javascript file available at a particular link, and use the function declared in that file to process some data.

What i would like to achieve is something like the following in html -

```
<script src="https://some-link/Data.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var testVariable = someMethod(localdata);
});
//use testVariable as necessary
</script>
```

//someMethod() is declared in remotely available Data.js

I am a newb at Appcelerator and im not really able to follow some of the threads i have come across, so some detailed help would be really appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well according to me , you should first understand few points first :

1. You want to include a remote file hosted at some server , now as the Titanium code converts to native code at compile time , you cannot include Titanium API's from remote file.
2. If you want to include a remote file , then only option which I see is loading that file in [webview](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.WebView).

Now coming to your problem , as you said that you want to fetch some data only from remote server by triggering some JS function from remote file. So following is what would I do :-

a/ Create a hidden [webview](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.WebView) in my main window with a EventListener of webview. Something like :

```
var webview = Titanium.UI.createWebView({url:'localHtmlFile.html'});

//event listener to handle the response from webview
Ti.App.addEventListener('fromWebView', function(e) 
{ 
    var testVariable = e.data; 
});
```

b/ In localHtmlFile.html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
     <script src="https://some-link/Data.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
          var testVariable = someMethod();
          //respond the fetch data to the main window via fireEvent
          Ti.App.fireEvent( 'fromWebView', { data : testVariable } );
     });
     </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**PS : This is just a logic to begin with , you have to edit code according to your requirements**

Comment: Thank you Sumit for pointing me in the right direction. Got it to work based on your advice. Much Obliged. :-)

Comment: It's incorrect that Titanium converts to native at compile time. You can use eval function to execute arbitrary code.

Comment: Can you provide some example for same, i will test and update my answer accordingly.